# Android Spinner for datepicker

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, spinner

For a project, I need to make a spinner with a DatePicker, like this one :

[image: DatePicker Spinner]

But I don't know how to achieve this... I saw `datepickermode="spinner"` but my app have to run on api level 19. My app is developped using Kotlin.

Someone can help me ?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `datepickermode=”spinner”` and also, `timepickermode=”spinner”` don't quite work on Android 7.0 or higher API levels.  Follow these steps and check if it works accordingly:

`build.gradle (project-level)`

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}
```

`build.gradle (app-level)`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.Ibotta:Supported-Picker-Dialogs:1.0.0'
}
```

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

Implement the `DatePicker` in your Kotlin code like this:

```kotlin
val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance()
val year = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val dayOfMonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
SupportedDatePickerDialog(this, R.style.SpinnerDatePickerDialogTheme, this, year, month, dayOfMonth).show()
```